# Where does spring rabbit consume a message on a new thread

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm working on tracing rabbitmq, and I've found that spring rabbit consumes a message on a new thread. I wanna know where does it create a new thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/receiving-messages/choose-container.html).

The (default) `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` passes the messages to a dedicated thread for each consumer; the thread(s) are created when the container is `start()`ed. You can specify a custom `TaskExecutor`. By default, it uses a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

The `DirectMessageListenerContainer` calls the listener on the amqp-client dispatcher thread.

Comment: I want to know how and where the message is passed across threads, from `com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer#handleDelivery` to `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer#invokeListener`

Comment: See `BlockingQueueConsumer`.

Comment: The link is dead.